# divide number into any of several sets of groups tidyverse r

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a dataset with three variables: order_id, total_apples, number_bags.
I'd like to divide the total_apples into the number_bags randomly in any way that works.
So if order 1 has 6 apples into 3 bags, the result could be: 1, 2, 3 or 4, 1, 1 or 3, 2, 1 etc.

I'd like to make a new output file that has:

```
order_id|bag_id|number_apples
1|1|4
1|2|1
1|3|1
```

Is there an easy way to do this in R tidyverse?
I've been trying things with sample and rep and making a mess of it

Thanks

Comment: Is each apple distinct? As in, if apples 1,2 went into bag 1, apples 3,4 into bag 2, and apples 5,6 into bag 3, is that different from apples 1,3 into bag 1, apples, 2,5 into bag 2, and apples 3,4 into bag 3?

Comment: not distinct, those two examples would be the same here: 2 apples in each bag

Comment: I can‘t create some code right now, but the process would be 1. find all factors of a number, e.g. 6 has 1,2,3,6. 7 has 1, 7. 10 has 1,2,5,10.  I‘ sure there are functions for that. 2. create all combinations with m= number of bags of these numbers (might not work for larger numbers anymore). 3. create the sum for each of these combinations and filter on those that sum to the number of apples.